# Ant - Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'nz-switch'

Tags: javascript, angular, antd, angular-ngmodel, ng-zorro-antd

I'm using Ant Design for Angular (ng-zorro-antd), and using the simple `switch` module to display a switch.

When I add the code per the docs:

`<nz-switch [ngModel]="true"></nz-switch>`

The app won't compile, and I get this error:

`Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'nz-switch'`

Comment: try to import FormsModule into a module where declared this component

Comment: You either forgot to import FormsModule in the parent module, or forgot to import the component(where you are using nz-switch)  inside the module where nz-switch module is placed.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that was it. The issue was that I was importing the FormsModule in a different "shared" module file. Once I moved it directly into the module where the switch is used I was good.

Answer (score 4):

**Import `FormsModule` in the right module**

While it doesn't say it in the [documentation](https://ng.ant.design/components/switch/en), you need to have Angular's `FormsModule` imported in order for the `ngModel` binding to work.

If you have an app with just one module, this is easy. Simply import the `FormsModule` as below in your one and only `xxx.module.ts` file.

If you're working on an app with multiple modules, you have to ensure you're importing it in the module where you're going to use the `nz-switch`

In *that* module, where you're using the `nz-switch`, in the `xxx.module.ts` file:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms`;

... 

@NgModule({
  declaration: [ ... ],
  imports: [ 
    ...,
    FormsModule
  ],
  ...
```

You should be good to go.